# Unable to download geoip module via luarocks

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, openresty, luarocks

I am trying to install geoip module via luarocks but it showing errors multiple times.
luarocks --from=http://geoip.luaforge.net/rocks install geoip --verbose

**Output**

io.popen:   'pwd'

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && test '-e' '/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && test '-d' '/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && test '-e' '/usr/local'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && test '-d' '/usr/local'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && test '-e' '/usr/local'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && mkdir -p '/root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && test '-d' '/root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks' && rm '-rf' '/root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks/manifest-5.1'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks' && unzip -n '/root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks/manifest-5.1.zip'
Archive:  /root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks/manifest-5.1.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks/manifest-5.1.zip or
        /root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks/manifest-5.1.zip.zip, and cannot find /root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks/manifest-5.1.zip.ZIP, period.
Results: 1
  1 (number): 2304

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && rm '-rf' '/root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks/manifest-5.1.zip'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && rm '-rf' '/root/.cache/luarocks/http___geoip.luaforge.net_rocks/manifest-5.1.zip.timestamp'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed extracting manifest file

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && mkdir -p '/root/.cache/luarocks/https___rocks.moonscript.org'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1' && test '-d' '/root/.cache/luarocks/https___rocks.moonscript.org'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/root/.cache/luarocks/https___rocks.moonscript.org' && rm '-rf' '/root/.cache/luarocks/https___rocks.moonscript.org/manifest-5.1'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

os.execute:     cd '/root/.cache/luarocks/https___rocks.moonscript.org' && unzip -n '/root/.cache/luarocks/https___rocks.moonscript.org/manifest-5.1.zip'
Archive:  /root/.cache/luarocks/https___rocks.moonscript.org/manifest-5.1.zip
  inflating: manifest-5.1
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0

Error: No results matching query were found.

but when i am able to dowloand this file **wget http://geoip.luaforge.net/rocks/manifest**
 can any one help on this.. where i am doing wrong..

also i tried with build
make
cc -Wall -ansi   -c -o geoip.o geoip.c
geoip.c:13:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
: recipe for target 'geoip.o' failed
make: *** [geoip.o] Error 1

luarocks version = /usr/bin/luarocks 2.2.0
OS = Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

https://luaforge.net is no longer maintained; you are using a deprecated URL.

For a current geoip library for Lua, use instead `luarocks install lua-geoip`.